# Get files one at a time from a folder in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file, timer, directory

I am trying to read some text files path in a folder sequentially. However, I get only the first file.

I need to get the first file, execute a timer, get the next file path, execute a timer right up to the last file in the folder, and stop. How can I get around this?

```
Private zMailbox As String = "c:\Fold\"

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
  Handles Button1.Click

    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim finfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)
    For Each fi In finfo.GetFiles("*.txt")
        TextBox1.Text = fi.FullName
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks to the contributions below I got the code to work with the text box value. However, it gives the index count instead of the path which I want to retrieve.

```
Private zMailbox As String = "c:\Fold\"

Dim files As FileInfo()
Dim index As Integer = 0


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
  Handles Button1.Click

    Dim finfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)
    files = finfo.GetFiles("*.txt")
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles Timer1.Tick

    If index >= files.Length Then
        index = 0
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = (ListBox1.Items.Add(files(index)))

    index += 1

End Sub
```

Comment: that is not going to do what you think.  It will do GetFiles on every tick.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit Rube Goldberg-ish. Just get all the files and loop through them in your `Button_Click` method:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim finfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)
    For Each fi In finfo.GetFiles("*.txt")
        TextBox1.Text = fi.FullName
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code loads all the files in the Timer event and assign them to the TextBox1.Text property  inside the loop. Every loop overwrites the data that has been written in the previous loop. 
At the end of the loop you see only the last value.

To show sequentially the files inside the Timer Tick event, you need to read the directory content before starting the Timer in a global FileInfo array. Another global variable will be used as indexer to show a particular file from this FileInfo array in your Timer.Tick event.
The index will be incremented and, at the next Tick, you could show the next file

```
Dim files as FileInfo()
Dim index As Integer = 0


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim finfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)
    files = finfo.GetFiles("*.txt")
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    if index >= files.Length Then
        index = 0
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = files(index)
    index += 1
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
According to your comment, you need to set the `MultiLine` property of the TextBox to true (using the form designer) and then, at every Tick, instead of replacing the Text property, append to it

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    if index >= files.Length Then
        return ' Reached the end of the array. Stop the Timer???
    End If
    TextBox1.AppendText(files(index) & Environment.NewLine)
    index += 1
End Sub
```

As a side note, if you want to show all file names together then it is not clear why you need a timer at all.
You could get the same result with code like this

```
Dim finfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)
Dim files = finfo.EnumerateFiles("*.txt")
TextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, files.Select(Function(x) x.FullName).ToArray())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help however it still just gives me 1 file in the text box. I woukd like the text box to be able to load the next file path and so forth. Thanks

Comment: Then you need to set the MultiLine property of the TextBox to true, and instead of replacing the current text append to the current one. Trying to fix the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. The Multiline Property of the textbox had been activated all along. Still stuck with one path after executing both codes. I wonder what might be missing as all approaches have given the same result.

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to get all the paths at the same time. I would like to get each path separately after the timers executed code.

Comment: Did you give to your TextBox enough Height to show more than one single line? Perhaps a ListBox is better suited for this?

Comment: I think so, however what I have in mind is to be able to grab each path after the timers executed code and store in a variable. Trying with the Listbox Control.

Comment: Thanks alot got it working with the listbox control . Still going to play around with other controls .

Answer (score 0):

On the original code you posted you where getting all files in the for loop each time the timer clicks.
After reading steve answer, and your comments, probably you always got all the files, but you override the textbox.text value.

> TextBox1.Text **+=** < String > & vbNewLine

Where < String >, of course, is the string returned by DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()

I think steve answer works just fine, but you are not implementing it well.

Comment: Thank you , I want to get the variable(path) thats sent out each time by the loop and store in a string. I would like to use this string value elsewhere in my code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would try and make this as easy as possible for you. You Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. Just NuGet "Rx-Main".

Here's what you can then do:

```
finfo.GetFiles("*.txt").ToObservable() _
    .Zip(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)), Function(f, _) f.Name) _
    .ObserveOn(TextBox1) _
    .Subscribe(Function(n) textbox_text += n + Environment.NewLine)
```

That's it. No timers. No separate methods. No need for module-level variables. Just one line of code and you're done.

It's processed on a background thread and then marshalled back to the UI via the `.ObserveOn(TextBox1)` call.

You can even keep a reference to the `IDisposable` returned by the `.Subscribe(...)` call to terminate the observable (timer) early.

Simple.